# Python - convert unicode and hex to unicode

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, mojibake

I have a supposedly unicode string like this:

> u'\xc3\xa3\xc6\u2019\xc2\xa9\xc3\xa3\xc6\u2019\xe2\u20ac\u201c\xc3\xa3\xc6\u2019\xc2\xa9\xc3\xa3\xe2\u20ac\u0161\xc2\xa4\xc3\xa3\xc6\u2019\xe2\u20ac\u201c\xc3\xaf\xc2\xbc\xc2\x81\xc3\xa3\xe2\u20ac\u0161\xc2\xb9\xc3\xa3\xe2\u20ac\u0161\xc2\xaf\xc3\xa3\xc6\u2019\xc2\xbc\xc3\xa3\xc6\u2019\xc2\xab\xc3\xa3\xe2\u20ac\u0161\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa3\xe2\u20ac\u0161\xc2\xa4\xc3\xa3\xc6\u2019\xe2\u20ac\xb0\xc3\xa3\xc6\u2019\xc2\xab\xc3\xa3\xc6\u2019\xe2\u20ac\xa2\xc3\xa3\xe2\u20ac\u0161\xc2\xa7\xc3\xa3\xe2\u20ac\u0161\xc2\xb9\xc3\xa3\xc6\u2019\xe2\u20ac\xa0\xc3\xa3\xe2\u20ac\u0161\xc2\xa3\xc3\xa3\xc6\u2019\xc2\x90\xc3\xa3\xc6\u2019\xc2\xab\xc3\xaf\xc2\xbc\xcb\u2020\xc3\xa3\xe2\u20ac\u0161\xc2\xb9\xc3\xa3\xe2\u20ac\u0161\xc2\xaf\xc3\xa3\xc6\u2019\xe2\u20ac\xa2\xc3\xa3\xe2\u20ac\u0161\xc2\xa7\xc3\xa3\xe2\u20ac\u0161\xc2\xb9\xc3\xaf\xc2\xbc\xe2\u20ac\xb0'

How do I get the correct unicode string out of this? I think, the actual unicode value is `ラブライブ！スクールアイドルフェスティバル（スクフェス）`

Comment: This is a mojibake. How did you get that value? It's incorrectly decoded.

Comment: You're confused about the meaning of "unicode string".

Comment: Even better, this was mangled **twice**. UTF-8, decoded as CP1252, then encoded as UTF-8 again, then decoded as CP1252 again. Quite a feat!

Comment: @IrmendeJong I guess. I see u'' and '\u2019' in the string. So, I assumed it's unicode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), an incorrectly decoded piece text.

You can use the [`ftfy` library](http://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to un-do the damage:

```
>>> from ftfy import fix_text
>>> fix_text(s)
u'\u30e9\u30d6\u30e9\u30a4\u30d6!\u30b9\u30af\u30fc\u30eb\u30a2\u30a4\u30c9\u30eb\u30d5\u30a7\u30b9\u30c6\u30a3\u30d0\u30eb(\u30b9\u30af\u30d5\u30a7\u30b9)'
>>> print fix_text(s)
ラブライブ!スクールアイドルフェスティバル(スクフェス)
```

According to `ftfy`, your data was encoded as UTF-8, then decoded as Windows codepage 1252; the [`ftfy.fixes.fix_one_step_and_explain()` function](http://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#ftfy.fixes.fix_one_step_and_explain) shows the repair steps needed:

```
>>> ftfy.fixes.fix_one_step_and_explain(s)[-1]
[(u'encode', u'sloppy-windows-1252', 0), (u'decode', u'utf-8', 0)]
```

(the ['sloppy' encoding](http://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#module-ftfy.bad_codecs.sloppy) is needed because not all UTF-8 bytes can be decoded as `cp1252`, but some bad decoders then just copy the original byte; the special codec reverses that process).

In fact, in your case this was done ***twice***, not a feat I had seen before:

```
>>> print s.encode('sloppy-cp1252').decode('utf8').encode('sloppy-cp1252').decode('utf8')
ラブライブ！スクールアイドルフェスティバル（スクフェス）
```

Comment: Awesome, ftfy works. I got this value from an API. I was told that the following function was used in PHP.

mb_convert_encoding($program_name, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');

Comment: @Sri: they did much more to this; re-coding from UTF-8 to UTF-8 is a no-op anyway.

Comment: I see. I have forwarded this page URL to the client. I hope he/she will fix it.